# Account linking returns errors

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am facing issue with account linking in google action console. What should be parameter in the https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com for successful account linking and redirecting me back to simulator?

Firstly I have used auth0 for account linking. It was successful v.i.a simulator i.e It was opening the auth0 login page where I logged in and it was showing me "Account Linking Successful" and redirecting me back to google simulator page for further testing. But when I used my website for authentication It is returning error while Account linking.

https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/airpurifier-dlfvrq?state=MY_STATE&access_token=KkvQ85d36b1ebcf0cea06a5148236tdVEp&token_type=bearer

returns "The parameter "code" or "error" must be set in the query string". as error message

When I intentionally add

https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/airpurifier-dlfvrq?state=MY_STATE&access_token=KkvQ85d36b1ebcf0cea06a5148236tdVEp&token_type=bearer&code=200

An error occurred in returning the result.

I have followed the entire documentation from https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation the return URL should be in below format:

```
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&state=STATE_STRING
```

Notice that you are using "?" after project ID which should be "#". Change it and try. It should work.

Comment: Initially, on following the documentation it weren't working while I used the link urlParams.redirect_uri+'#&state='+urlParams.state+'&access_token='+userId+'&token_type=bearer' and it worked. 

where redirect uri is [link](https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID)
Thanks

Comment: Glad to know you could fix the issue Sourav!

Comment: Putting the data into the link instead of query data worked for me, too. As on amazon this is in the query data and at google it is in the url.